# How to recognise in Java when web project is deployed?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a simple web project which changes a line of text with another at the click of a button. What I want is a `core Java` method which will recognise when the `.war` file is deployed on the Tomcat server.

I want to output the exact time when the deployment happens. I have the code ready for that, and I want it to be in `core Java`.

Is there any such method that will allow me to perform some activity when the deployment happens?

Comment: why you add JavaScript Tag in Your question

Comment: i know for sure this is done automatically if you are using maven

Comment: So, the Tomcat server is running a separate VM from some other Java code, and you want this Java code to know when a new .war file has been dropped? The most straightforward manner would be to have the Java program monitor a file listener on the warfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [**`ServletContextListener`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

Add a `<listener>` tag in your `web.xml` file as follows:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>classes.MyListener</listener-class>  
</listener>
```

And make a `Java` class implement the `ServletContextListener` interface. Overriding the `contextInitialized()` method and writing your code in it will do the trick.

For example:

```
package classes;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        System.out.println("Project deployed: " + new DateTime());
        //or any other form of output
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        System.out.println("Project undeployed: " + new DateTime());
        //or any other form of output
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Look to see if the WAR file has been unzipped (exploded) in the webapps directory.  This itself can be done two different ways, by looking to see if the exploded directory is there.  Or by looking at the access time of the WAR file.  Please note to see the access time of a file in *nix you have to use the `-u` option in the `ls` command.

But this has a flaw in the you cannot tell when the webservice has finished initializing.  For that you can create a keepAlive service that you can poll in your webservice.  That way when your application is done initializing you will get a response from the keepAlive.  You can set a high loadnumber on this service to allow all the other Servlets to load first.

```
curl "http:localhost:8080/MyWebService/keepAlive"
```

Furthermore, I know specifically with Tomcat you can query its JMX monitor.  I do not know if it has a JMX query to list out loaded Servlets, but it might and it is extensible so you can add your own queries for finding that out.

EDIT:  You can also setup your Servlet to log when it is done initializing.  Then just `grep "your services' log msg"` in a loop till it exits with exit code 0.